# Как подключиться к MSSQL в Drupal 7

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, drupal7

Мне надо в форме вывести поля которые хранятся в другой БД MSSQL, но при этом мне не нужно менять подключение в настройках.
Я создаю модуль для подключения(включаю его), но оно не работает, все слетает.
Начало при включении модуля в админке выдавать 500-ую ошибку.
Я погнал в page.tpl.php и добавил туда этот код.. После обновления, просто белая страничка, ошибок нет..

Спасибо за помощь.

```
<?php

$serverName = "test"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testdb", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"qwer");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
   echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
   echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: А модуль php для работы с mssql вы установили?

Comment: @DenisStartsev: sql server модуль устанавливал

Comment: В логах php определенно что то должно быть